# Why "No such device or address" when open /dev/tty in the first process?

Tags: tty

Given that a simple program, as following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int fd = -1;

  if (access("/dev/tty", F_OK) == 0)
    {
      fd = open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR);
      if (fd == -1)
        perror("open() :");
    }

   return 0;
}
```

compile and make it as init (the frist process invoked by kernel), then reboot, but it would get the result:

```
open() :No such device or address
```

How to explain this ?

Comment: This sounds like an X Y problem.  Why do you want to open /dev/tty ?  Explain that, and you will get a better answer.

Comment: The idea is to make the /dev/tty as the controlling terminal of the process ...

Comment: No.  /dev/tty is not a terminal.  Use another device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/dev/tty` is a reference to the controlling terminal for a process.  But in order for it to have a controlling terminal, a real terminal has to be opened and been assigned to the process.

Perhaps instead of opening /dev/tty you should open /dev/tty0 or /dev/console or /dev/tty1

If a process does not have a controlling terminal, and it opens a tty or pty, if nothing else is using that tty as a controlling terminal already, then the process will be assigned that tty as a controlling terminal.  It is also possible to open a tty and assign it as the controlling terminal with an IOCTL if the conditions are correct.

However /dev/tty is not a real tty, so these conditions don't apply to it.

Comment: What do you mean "been assigned to it" ?

Comment: expanded answer.  But you're focusing on the wrong part.  You have to open a real tty first and `/dev/tty` is not a real tty and doesn't point to one until you have a controlling terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Answer of @user110489 works for me.

What you have to do is replace the `/dev/tty` with `/dev/console`.

**My system Configs:**

```
OS - windows 10
IDE - VSCode
Error arrise in - husky hooks.
```

Comment: Please don’t post a new answer just to say that another answer worked for you — especially if you aren't using Unix/Linux.

Comment: This probably should have been a comment.  /dev/console sometimes is another special tty

Comment: This is posted because I came here searching for husky hooks' solution. And I guess many other may have faced the same error.